# KERBEROS error while running mapreduce on Hbase

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase, kerberos, hadoop-yarn

I am new to `KERBEROS` and getting the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Can't get Master Kerberos principal for use as renewer
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
    at SampleUploader.main(SampleUploader.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

This error occurs when I run the following code (available in GitHub: https://github.com/ddraj/hbase-trunk-mttr/blob/master/hbase-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/SampleUploader.java)

```
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
conf.set("dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal","hdfs/_HOST@REALM.COM");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
System.out.println(UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser()+"***********");
```

I am using CDH5.2.6

I am able to get the login user like so:

```
System.out.println(UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser()+"***********");
```

Comment: What is the code that produces this error?

Comment: Its aTableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal working code example that reproduces the error?

Comment: Please refer the code in GitHub:

https://github.com/ddraj/hbase-trunk-mttr/blob/master/hbase-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/SampleUploader.java

with additional codes:

conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        conf.set("dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal","hdfs/_HOST@REALM.COM");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        System.out.println(UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser()+"***********");

Answer (score 2):

This error usually means what it says it means (that it can't find a specific Kerberos principal to use for some operation). The details of resolving this error, however, are awful. It usually boils down to these three things:

1. You're using a .jaas file and the principals are wrong there, or you're not using a .jaas file when you should. Make sure you're using "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=[.jaas file]" on your java call.
2. Some already-defined principal in some Hadoop-related config file is wrong or is unknown to Kerberos. This can be because any of the parts of the principal are wrong (verify the user, host and realm) or because nobody has the Kerberos ticket granting ticket for the current, real user (use kinit or do this in your app.)
3. You need to define a property in some Hadoop-related config file. It's possible that you don't know about the property yet and -- here's the awful part -- it's also possible you **don't even know about the config file itself.** For instance, exporting snapshots in HBase 0.98.x requires a yarn-site.xml file; two principals need to be defined there. I have no idea why, since yarn isn't mentioned in the HBase reference, I'm not using Yarn and I don't have Yarn installed.

Unfortunately, #3 is responsible for at least half of the hours I burned -- wasted -- trying to get HBase going with Kerberos. I have stopped counting the actual number of hours because it just got me frustrated. Hopefully this post will help other folks not waste their time.